# Using the Atlassian JIRA API, log in without using plaintext password

Tags: php, json, api, passwords, jira

I'm playing around with integrating Jira into our current PHP based website and I am wondering if their is anyway I can authenticate users using something other than a plaintext password. I don't really want to store the plaintext passwords in the website database. The script below is a script I found and I've been playing around with querying and such. I would like to authenticate the user as soon as they log into the backend of our website. Is it possible to authenticate someone without a plaintext password?

```
<?php



    $username = '******';

    $password = '*****';



    $url = "https://jira.*****/rest/api/2/search?jql=****";

    $ch = curl_init();



    $headers = array(

        'Accept: application/json',

        'Content-Type: application/json'

    );



    $test = "This is the content of the custom field.";



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");



    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $ch_error = curl_error($ch);

    if ($ch_error) {

        echo "cURL Error: $ch_error";

    } else {

        $phpData = json_decode($result);
        foreach($phpData->issues as $issue){
            print_r($issue)
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Comment: For the next one having problems with this.
Here you can see a full example: https://github.com/alexzv/jira-restapi-client/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use OAuth to perform the initial authentication of the user to JIRA then store their oauth token in their session and use it for future requests.

Here is the link to the PHP OAuth Example they have in Bit Bucket:

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/d625161454d1ca97b4515c6147b093fac9a68f7e/php/?at=default